# Fill the remaining space of the page with static field

Tags: jasper-reports

I have created a report which is basically a timesheet for the employee to fill-in, so it’s a table where one row is designed to be prefilled with employee’s data (ex : name / last name…).

My SQL request retrieves 16 employees record. One page contains only 13 rows, so it will automatically create a second page for the last 3 rows. My problem (and requirement) is to create a second page containing 13 rows, 3 of them will be filled with records, and 10 of them will be left blank.

Here is an example:

[image]

How can I do that?

What if I want to create an extra-page with 13 blank rows?

Can someone help me please?

Comment: Do you want to add the fixed numbers of rows or dynamic (depends on the "free" space on the page)?

Comment: Actually it would be better to do it dynamically to avoid spending too much time if the height of one row changes.

Comment: Created a pull request to add property to JasperReports to fill with empty rows. https://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/1121141/created-pull-request-... https://github.com/ozawa-hi/jasperreports/tree/fill_with_rows

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I got my answer on the jaspersoft communauty forum : http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/817708/resolved-how-fill-reports-blank-space-empty-row-table

The principle is to customize the background's band, here is in an example of the model :

```
<background>
<band height="555" splitType="Stretch">
<rectangle>
<reportElement uuid="ee3fa6a5-eddb-4b38-b834-f2658bcf92d1" x="0" y="59" width="800" height="427"/>
</rectangle>
<line>
<reportElement uuid="4494e946-4ff5-4d57-b3eb-9d64eda302c4" x="0" y="95" width="800" height="1"/>
</line>
<line>
<reportElement uuid="4494e946-4ff5-4d57-b3eb-9d64eda302c4" x="0" y="125" width="800" height="1"/>
</line>
<line>
<reportElement uuid="4494e946-4ff5-4d57-b3eb-9d64eda302c4" x="0" y="155" width="800" height="1"/>
</line>
<line>
<reportElement uuid="4494e946-4ff5-4d57-b3eb-9d64eda302c4" x="0" y="185" width="800" height="1"/>
</line>
<line>
<reportElement uuid="4494e946-4ff5-4d57-b3eb-9d64eda302c4" x="0" y="215" width="800" height="1"/>
</line>
<line>
<reportElement uuid="4494e946-4ff5-4d57-b3eb-9d64eda302c4" x="0" y="245" width="800" height="1"/>
</line>
<line>
<reportElement uuid="4494e946-4ff5-4d57-b3eb-9d64eda302c4" x="0" y="275" width="800" height="1"/>
</line>
<line>
<reportElement uuid="4494e946-4ff5-4d57-b3eb-9d64eda302c4" x="0" y="305" width="800" height="1"/>
</line>
<line>
<reportElement uuid="4494e946-4ff5-4d57-b3eb-9d64eda302c4" x="0" y="335" width="800" height="1"/>
</line>
<line>
<reportElement uuid="4494e946-4ff5-4d57-b3eb-9d64eda302c4" x="0" y="365" width="800" height="1"/>
</line>
<line>
<reportElement uuid="4494e946-4ff5-4d57-b3eb-9d64eda302c4" x="0" y="395" width="800" height="1"/>
</line>
<line>
<reportElement uuid="4494e946-4ff5-4d57-b3eb-9d64eda302c4" x="0" y="425" width="800" height="1"/>
</line>
<line>
<reportElement uuid="4494e946-4ff5-4d57-b3eb-9d64eda302c4" x="0" y="455" width="800" height="1"/>
</line>
<line>
<reportElement uuid="01f3d5fc-9d23-4c7b-96cf-0ff7b3285400" x="160" y="59" width="1" height="427"/>
</line>
<line>
<reportElement uuid="01f3d5fc-9d23-4c7b-96cf-0ff7b3285400" x="320" y="59" width="1" height="427"/>
</line>
<line>
<reportElement uuid="01f3d5fc-9d23-4c7b-96cf-0ff7b3285400" x="480" y="59" width="1" height="427"/>
</line>
<line>
<reportElement uuid="01f3d5fc-9d23-4c7b-96cf-0ff7b3285400" x="639" y="59" width="1" height="427"/>
</line>
</band>
</background>
```

Answer (score 1):

Draw a grid on the background band, and change the property opaque to true in all the other bands.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what datasource you are using... If you are using Javaabeans as Datasource then it can be done easily. Just add 10 beans(with null values) and wholla...you will get 3(previous page record) + 10 (blank records) in the second page....
Moreover I insist you to complete your 13 records into single page by decresing the size of cells in a table or list whatever you have in your report..

Answer (score 0):

I got same problem and this helped me.
click on table in jrxml file on designer tab, go to properties and write '$V{REPORT_COUNT}==1' in print when expression field.
make sure you checked, 'Remove line when blank'.